# Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String[] to required type java.util.List spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, jsp, jpa

[image]

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String[] to
> required type java.util.List for property tags; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
> java.lang.String to required type edu.pxu.ri.MVCvaJPA.entity.Tag for
> property tags[0]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

ManyToMany ORM

Solution:

[image]

AppConfig:

[image]

Happy to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

package:converter

```
 @Component
    public class TagConverter implements Converter<String[], List<Tag>> {
    
        @Autowired
        TagService tagService;
        
        @Override
        public List<Tag> convert(String[] arg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             List<Tag> tagList = new ArrayList<>();
                System.out.println("tags String[]"+arg);
                    for (String tag : (String[])arg) {
                        System.out.println("tagId:"+tag);
                        Tag tagUd = tagService.getTagById(Integer.valueOf(tag));
                        tagList.add(tagUd);          
                    }
             return tagList;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "edu.pxu.ri.MVCvaJPA"
})
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    TagConverter tagConverter;
    
    @Autowired
    TagConverterString tagConverterString;
    
    @Override
     public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
         registry.addConverter(tagConverter);
         registry.addConverter(tagConverterString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).